# Magento 2 - How to add a custom field in admin/sales/order/view

Tags: magento2, attributes, adminhtml, sales-order, custom-attributes

How can I add a custom field to admin/sales/order/view?

I'm trying to add a tracking number field to the sales order view.

The tracking number must be saved in the db.

Comment: Learn this blog https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-new-section-to-admin-sales-order-view-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you for the comment, additionally, I want that filed to be editable. so I can add and save the tracking number for the order.

Answer (score 0):

sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="require_verification">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Require Verification</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="verify">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">verify</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Verify</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="verification/order/verify"/>
                        <item name="param" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status Verfication</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                                Are you sure you wan't to change the status of
                                selected items?
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 0):

etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid"
                 type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="require_verification" xsi:type="string">sales_order.require_verification</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

add column in existing table

etc/db_schema.xml

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Flat
Order">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="require_verification" padding="5"
                unsigned="true" nullable="true" identity="false" comment="Require Verification"/>
    </table>
    <table name="sales_order_grid" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Flat
Order Grid">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="require_verification" padding="5"
                unsigned="true" nullable="true" identity="false" comment="Require Verification"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="require_verification_frontend"
                  instance="Moazzam\RequireVerification\Observer\Frontend\Verification"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\RequireVerification\Observer\Frontend;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * PLEASE ENTER ONE LINE SHORT DESCRIPTION OF CLASS
 *
 * Class Verification
 */
class Verification implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private State $state;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param State $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        State $state
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Set the verification of custom attribute of sales_order
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->setRequireVerification(1)->save();
        $this->logger->info('order saving...' . PHP_EOL, [$this->state->getAreaCode(),
        $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData()]);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\RequireVerification\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

/**
 * PLEASE ENTER ONE LINE SHORT DESCRIPTION OF CLASS
 *
 * Class Verify
 */
class Verify extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    private Filter $filter;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collection
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collection
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collection;
        $this->filter=$filter;
    }

    /**
     * @return Redirect
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(): Redirect
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            if ($order->getStatus() == 'pending') {
                $order->setRequireVerification(0)->save();
            }
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__(
            'A total of %1 record(s) have been modified.',
            $collection->getSize()
        ));
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/index');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```